# Android validation is not a number from EditText

Tags: android, validation, numbers, android-edittext

mail_xml is this:

```
EditText android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned`
```

onTextChanged implemented on this and other edittexts and calls relative methods.

```
//and one method example:
if (editTextNumber.getText().toString().equals("") ||                
    editTextNumber.getText().toString().equals("-") ||  
    editTextNumber.getText().toString().equals(".")) {
//say its bad or reset interface so the user knows;

else {
//do stuff;
}
```

Should I create a class to do the validation and instantiate it, then use an if/else statement returning a boolean?

It's difficult because a `-` is valid as the user types, so is a `.`. But a `.` and `-` crashes. I'm thinking a class would be best?

I don't remember a function in java to do this, unless the api has been updated and I haven't seen it yet. I've created the classes i need and can instantiate them call their getter methods no problem. just stuck on the basic validation.

Comment: Its so difficult to understand what you need here. Please rephrase.

Comment: sorry i was really struggling with the interface to actually upload what i had written. i want to take user input from an edittext and check they have a valid number and do calculations on that. most of my code is done but i am stuck on the validation of user input on the soft keypad. hope that makes sense.

Comment: u need to repharse, else it will get downvoted soon.

Comment: very annoying i wrote more than what you can see on this page unfortunately.

Comment: more annoying to read what you are commenting and making no sense what so ever.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Just add a method (or if its really that complex a class) to check the input.

Comment: ok it doesn't need to be like that. i have used forum allot in the past in my coding career. i'm just lost on this site and i did read how to post. i will post my code up when it's done.

Comment: Rarw, so instead of using an if statement with all the or clauses a class would be best practice? i have many fields to validate on each text change on the edit texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put the cast in a block try/catch...
This way if the text inserted is not a number, an exception is fired...
For exemple:

```
if(editTextNumber.getText()!=null && !editTextNumber.getText().toString().equals("")){
try{
    // int value
    Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber.getText().toString());
    // double value
    Double.parseDouble(editTextNumber.getText().toString());
}catch(Exception e){
    //prints the exception that you got
    //if number format exception then your input is not a number
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Hope it helped...

Comment: Thank you. try and catch was what i was missing. logcat better though. printStackTrace doesn't work.

Comment: and for future reference, could someone point me in the right direction of how to actually post notes and code on this site so we don't have the issues we have just had. i'm used to php forums. so i apologise.

Comment: Siddharth, that looks great and will to what is needed but would it be best in a class to simplify the code? I have n number of edit texts all responding to user input.

Comment: Next time show some of your real code and errors...
This way is far more easy to see were you are mistaken...

Comment: yes and noted thank you Manuel Pires. I know what to do now, i'll create a class and when i instantiate it i will pass it a view object, with a string if there is no exception. this might as well be closed and i'll redo one that works. sorry people, you have been patient for a newcomer here.